# How get the value of counter in python for loop

Tags: python

What is the best way to fix the following code

```
my_list=[]
elem={}
for i in range(4):
    elem['id']=i
    my_list.append(elem)
print my_list
```

result

```
[{'id': 3}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 3}]
```

expected result

```
[{'id': 0}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
```

**I don't want to use another variable

Answer (score 4):

You need to empty the dictionary inside the for loop itself.

```
my_list=[]
elem={}
for i in range(4):
    elem['id']=i
    my_list.append(elem)
    elem={}
print my_list
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 0}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
```

OR

simply,

```
my_list=[]
for i in range(4):
    elem = {}
    elem['id']=i
    my_list.append(elem)

print my_list
```

Comment: `for i in range(4): elem={} elem['id']=i my_list.append(elem)` I think we don't need to declare `elem={}` twice.

Comment: We can also move elem={} as the first statement within the loop and get rid of the first one right before the loop.

Comment: @TanveerAlam elem is never declared twice during execution. It's just that the code can be shrunk down and be better structured.

Comment: @Tarik I just went through your profile Sir and I think you have typo error in about me section. You have mentioned `Haslell` which should be `Haskell ` I think.

Answer (score 4):

Pythonic way: list comprehension

```
>>> [{'id':x} for x in range(4)]
[{'id': 0}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my_list = []
for i in range(4):
    mylist.append({'id': i})
```

This is practically equivalent to:

```
my_list = [{'id': i} for i in range(4)]
```